# How do I make a circled frame?

Tags: lyx, xy-pic

I'm using LYX at XyMatrix.

If I'm writing in one of the cells a code like that:

```
\save"1,1"."1,2"*+[r][F]\frm{}\restore
```

I get a rectangle frame.

If want to get a circled frame what should I write? If I'll write  something like:

```
\save"1,1"."1,2"*+[o][F]\frm{}\restore
```

I will get the first cell (1,1) circled.

Answer (score 3):

I found how to make it!

I have to write something like:

```
\save"1,1"."1,2"*++\frm<60pt>{-}\restore
```

And I'll get circled frame...

I have  to put an `-` inside the `{}` of `\frm`
and before it to put a `<X pt>`. `X` is the dimension.